# Проверка, авторизован ли пользователь в шаблоне freemarker

Tags: java, spring-mvc, freemarker

Разрабатываю проект на Spring MVC, Spring Boot, Spring Security, и в качестве шаблонизатора использую Freemarker. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы если посетитель сайта не авторизован, отображать ссылку для перехода на страницу авторизации, в противном случае кнопку Logout. Есть ли возможность у Freemarker проверять, авторизован ли пользователь (например из переменной сессии)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347589/checking-spring-security-roles-and-logged-username-in-freemarker-template

Answer (score -1):

<#if error??>
loginPage

1. @PostMapping("/sing_up")
   public  String addUser(@ModelAttribute @Valid User user, BindingResult result){
       userValidator.validate(user,result);
       if (result.hasErrors()){
           return "sing_up";
       }else userService.save(user);
       return "redirect:/users";
   }

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]